# Is it possible to modify this regex to NOT match string if its 4 digits?

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex to match @username strings (twitter like username match system).

```
(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)
```

This code is working perfectly for me, but wanted to exclude one certain case: If the matching string was a set of 4 digits.  ONLY 4 digits.  If there are 3 digits or 5 digits then it should continue to match as it does now.

So for example:

@8500 <-- don't match

@850 <-- match

@8500000000 <-- match

Is there an easy modification anyone can think of?   If not I was planning on just doing the check in PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a negative lookahead `(?!...)`, you can check to see if the following pattern does *not* match at the current position:

```
(?<![\w@])@(?!\d\d\d\d\b)([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)
```

The negative lookahead in question here is `(?!\d\d\d\d\b)`. The pattern will match four digits and then a word boundary. Inverted by the negative lookahead, this will match anything that is *not* four digits and then the end of the word.

This assumes that a valid username does not contain any characters that would cause a word boundary match. If `@1234-hello` was a valid username, this would fail, and you would need to perform the match in PHP.

Some example test cases follow:

```
<?php

function test($test) {
    $pattern = '/(?<![\w@])@(?!\d\d\d\d\b)([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/';
    echo (preg_match($pattern, $test) ? 'Matches' : 'No match') . "\n";
}

test('Hello @test world'); // Matches
test('Hello @123 world'); // Matches
test('Hello @1234 world'); // No match
test('Hello @12345 world'); // Matches
test('Hello @test1234 world'); // Matches
test('Hello @1234test world'); // Matches
test('Hello @1234-test world'); // No match
test('Hello @1234_test world'); // Matches
```

Comment: I think you nailed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
if(strlen($string) != 4){
    ...regex here...
}
```

Comment: if((strlen($string) != 4) || (is_int($string) === false))

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the min/max number of matches for a regex token using `{min,max}` syntax, so you could use a snippet such as this to match either 1-3 or 5 or more digits (`\d`), surrounded by non-digit characters (`\D`):

```
/\D*(\d{1,3}|\d{5,})\D*/
```